# CSS: hiding elements for browsers with no javascript support

Tags: html, css, modernizr

So I use Modernizr to detect javascript. Based on the `.no-js` class, I have the following:

```
html.no-js .navContainer {
    visibility: visible !important;
}
.navContainer{
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

If the user has javascript enabled, the element is hidden. If they do not have javascript enabled, the element is visible.

Works great. Now I want to do the reverse. That is, I want an element *hidden* if the user doesn't have javascript. What is the best way to do that?

I've tried a number of things, including numerous variations on this:

```
html.no-js .navButton {
    display: none;
}

html .navButton {
    display: block;
}
```

but so far, nothing has worked. It's my understanding that `html.no-js .navButton` should only be selecting on `<html class="no-js">`. Is that not the case?

Comment: Are you sure you're disabling JS or at least not loading Modernizr? Otherwise you might have a more specific CSS rule that's overwriting the one you posted in your question.

Comment: I'm using a chrome plugin to disable and enable JS. You think the CSS is valid/should do what want?

Comment: Yes, if you have the `no-js` class on the `<html>` element in the source and nothing is removing it then the `.navButton` element(s) should be hidden. Proof of concept: http://jsfiddle.net/g8pobtda/. I suggest you create a JSFiddle and reproduce your issue.

Comment: Well, now everything is working fine. I must have had deadline fatigue. Thanks for looking at the question...

I will add one little refinement to the above. It should probably read `html.no-js .navbutton` and `html.js .navbutton` as to make the intent obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try putting it in page directly like below.

```
<noscript>
 <style type="text/css">
 @import url (nojs.css);

 .navButton {
     display: none;
 }

 </style>
 </noscript>
```

Comment: This is probably the better solution, actually.

Answer (score 0):

To hide visually and from screen readers use

```
html.no-js .navbutton {
  display: none
}
```

If you want to hide visually and from screen readers, but maintain layout:

```
html.no-js .navbutton {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

To hide only visually, but have it available for screen readers:

```
html.no-js .navbutton {
  border: 0;
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  height: 1px;
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
}
```

To extends the previous style to allow the element to be focusable when navigated to via the keyboard:

```
html.no-js .navbutton.focusable:active,
html.no-js .navbutton.focusable:focus {
  clip: auto;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: visible;
  position: static;
  width: auto;
}
```

Sources

- [HTML5Boilerplate](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/src/css/main.css)
- [Hiding content for accessibility](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/hiding-content-for-accessibility)